I have an error that I don't understand in flutter web deployed in production
I did not know why the error started, I had already deployed to production and it worked fine. The idea is that it enters the URL, once there it accepts the permissions for notifications, then it is directed to login, where it starts with credentials and when accessing the home page start to appear this type of errors in the browser console, it propagates to each screen I navigate to:
Navigator console
This is my index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="docochat">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>docochat</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
          .then(function(registration) {
            console.log(registration);
            console.log('Service Worker registrado con éxito con el alcance: ', registration.scope);
          }, function(err) {
            console.log('Service Worker falló en el registro', err);
          });
      });
    }
  </script>
  
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    if ('BroadcastChannel' in window) {
      const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages');
      channel.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
        /* console.log("Received in page", event.data); */
        localStorage.setItem('flutter.notificationExist', true);
        window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(event.data), '*');
      });
    }
  </script>  
</body>
</html>

I thought it was because of the console.logs I was doing in my index file but it didn't fix it, the weird thing is that it only happens to me in the Edge browser and in production, because when I'm running the application in a local environment I don't have any of those errors. The errors are always like that, I don't really understand the reason why they are generated.
